# Problem of file input() while using python code in VS Code editor

Tags: python

I do not know how to make my code in VS Code editor take a URL based file as input and read it.

I am trying to give the following file link:
'https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt'
and I am getting the following OS Error
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt'

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: What have you tried? You may find the *requests* module useful

Comment: Share your code, and what you're trying to do. The original question does not make the intent clear.

Comment: You cannot just open a URL as if it were a file.  YOU have to do a web request to fetch the file, and then open the local copy of the file.  `requests` can help you make that web request.

Answer (score 0):

The *requests* module (which you may need to install) will help in this case.

Something like this:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt' # input URL
OUTPUT = '/Volumes/G-Drive/regex_sum_42.txt' # output file
CHUNK = 4096 # a suitable chunk size

with requests.get(URL, stream=True) as response: # access the URL
    response.raise_for_status() # make sure the HTTP status is OK
    with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as output: # create the output file for writing (binary)
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK): # acquire data in chunks
            output.write(chunk) # write to the output file
```